# Give an example that shows there are $4\times4$ matrices over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Give an example that shows there are $4\times4$ matrices over  $\mathbb{Q}$ with the same characteristic and minimal polynomials that are not similar.

Comment: what are the possible Jordan forms with all characteristic values equal to $1 \; ?$

Answer (score 2):

Consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\\end{pmatrix}$.

Check that both have same minimal polynomial as well as characteristic polynomial. But since $rank(A)=2$ and $rank(B)=1$ they are not similer (why? See the [problem](http:///math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337598/prove-the-similar-matrices-have-the-same-rank) on MSE).

Comment: I think you meant $A$ to have a $1$ in position 3,4 as opposed to position 3,3 which is what it shows now

Comment: One of your ones is in the wrong place.

Comment: Sorry, typing mistake. I corrected it. Thank you for mention it.